# determine of data type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

I have User class in my project, where there is attribute imageUrl, but I am confused to determine the data type because it has to adjust to the data type  contained in the database that is BLOB. what is the appropriate data type?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Futsal
{
    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public String Fullname { get; set; }

        public String Email { get; set; }

        public String NoTelp { get; set; }

        public String Address { get; set; }

        public  ImageUrl { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know this `public  ImageUrl { get; set; }` should give an error as it only has a type and not a name

Comment: OP wants to know what data type to use @EpicKip

Comment: *the data type contained in the database that is BLOB* What does this means? Look at the relevant table designer and see what is it's type?

Comment: How are we supposed to know? You didn't even specify your database platform, your method of reading the data from the database, etc.

Comment: @PatrickHofman If its an url it should just be string, no need to make it harder than it is

Comment: It should be, but if the database data type is `blob`, what would it be?

Comment: @PatrickHofman A badly designed database?

Comment: That's for sure @EpicKip

Comment: Should the `ImageUrl` contain the actual image? if so, consider renaming it and use `Image` as your data type. If it should contain the URL of an image, then you can use `string` or `URI`.

Comment: i using mysql @PatrickHofman

Comment: It should be simply a `string` type- `public string ImageUrl { get; set; }`